# PowerShell - param [Int32]$Month displaying as single integer when it should have leading 0

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to pass parameters into my script here:

```
# Get current Year and Month
param ([Int32]$Year, [Int32]$Month, [String]$Environment, [String]$Report, [String]$Username, [String]$Password)

function Get-DaysOfMonth {
    Param ([Int32]$Year, [Int32]$Month)
    $MonthDays = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]
    1..([datetime]::DaysInMonth($Year, $Month)) |
        ForEach-Object {
           $Day = ([datetime]::ParseExact("$_/$Month/$Year", "d/M/yyyy", [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).ToString("dd")
           $MonthDays.Add($Day)
        }
    return $MonthDays
}

Write-Host ("The Year Selected is: {0}" -f $Year)
Write-Host ("The Month Selected is: {0}" -f $Month)
Write-Host ("The Environment Selected is: {0}" -f $Environment)
Write-Host ("The Report Generated is: {0}" -f $Report)
Write-Host ("Export Generating as User: {0}" -f $Username)
```

The problem is when running the following from command line:

```
myscript.ps1 -Year 2018 -Month 02 -Environment PROD -Report event -Username myname -Password mypass
```

It's re-parsing `02` as `2`

Comment: 02 is not a valid `[int32]`. So your code is explicitly telling it to drop the leading 0.

Comment: ok thnx @EBGreen so how do I get it to add back the leading 0?

Comment: `Write-Host ("The Month Selected is: {0:00}" -f $Month)`

Comment: got it.  just changed it to treat it as a string :)

Comment: You mean just so that you can display it in the Write-Host? `Write-Host ("The Month Selected is: {0:00}" -f $Month)`

Comment: @EBGreen For gods sake PowerShell doesn't treat leading zeroes with integers as octal as cmd.exe does. But otherwise once cast to an int the leading zeros will disappear they are **not** illegal per se.

Comment: I didn't say they were treated as octal. Just that converting them to int would remove the zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

02 is not a int. A number assigned to a int will remove the 0.

```
[int]$int = 02
$int
```

will display 2

you can reformat it as a string.

```
[int]$int = 02
$int.ToString("00")
```

will display 02